# working of Ethereum based chat Applications

Tags: ethereum

I am new to Ethereum, Blockchain Technology.I have been going through Tutorials on Ethereum and Smart Cotracts.

As per my Understanding, If we want to make any change to data members of the smart contact, it ll cost us some Ether right ? so , i am wondering how Free chat DApps work?. I mean, it should cost ether for storing the data of chats and transaction of data right ? or are they using any test networks such as kovan,rinkeby ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the public Ethereum blockchain it costs Ether to change data. It costs money to get these Ether so a Free chat on this network seems unlikely.

If you are using someone's private Ethereum blockchain it costs Ether to change data, but Ether has no value and can be given more or less easily (like Rinkeby).

If you are using your private Ethereum blockchain it costs Ether to change data, but you can get Ether easily at genesis block or mining Ether.

If you are using a private Ethereum blockchain like Quorum with GasPrice=0, you don't need Ether.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answer, I don't think so your referenced Apps are using Ethereum blockchain to save chat messages as it always requires Gas to add anything in a public Ethereum blockchain network. To integrate chatting in your App you can use [XMPP Framework](https://xmpp.org/).

Obviously you require to have a centralized server (Against the blockchain basic terminology) But chat history is not required to save on the server. It can only be saved on Users Device and can use end-to-end encryption. Server will only be required to implement socket-based communication by using XMPP framework. Or you can also use [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) for a chat. But I totally agree it's against the basic blockchain rule of decentralization.